# Assigning values from dynamic List to model properties. Conversion Errors

Tags: c#, dapper

New programmer having trouble assigning model property values from a stored procedure returning a dynamic list.

`Error: cant implicitly convert`.

and if I try using something like `Convert.ToDouble(Resultlist[0]);` that fails too.

The results list is returning expected values from the DB.

I am prrobably missing something very simple.

Model properties in this case are all doubles.

CODE:

```
public PricingOptionsModel GetPricing(PricingOptionsModel model)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString("Database")))
    {
        List<dynamic> Resultlist;
        Resultlist = connection.Query("dbo.GetCharges", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        model.item1 = Resultlist[0];
        model.item2 = Resultlist[1];
        model.item3 = Resultlist[2];
        model.item4 = Resultlist[3];
        model.item5 = Resultlist[4];
        model.item6 = Resultlist[5];
        model.item7 = Resultlist[6];
        model.item8 = Resultlist[7];

    }
    return model;
}
```

> > Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot
> >     implicitly convert type 'object' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'

Comment: What the stored procedure `dbo.GetCharges` looks like?

Comment: USE [database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure.[dbo].[GetCharges]

as 
SELECT top 1 [item1]
      ,[item2]
      ,[item3]
      ,[item4]
      ,[item5]
      ,[item6]
      ,[item7]
      ,[item8]
  FROM [dbo].[StaticData]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of your stored procedure, it provides a single row with multiple columns. `ResultList` has 1 item of type `object` and it has multiple properties (`item1`, `item2`, ...).

So you want to assign it like this: `model.item1 = ResultList[0].item1;`.

If types returned from Dapper don't match, then you can also apply `Convert` there like this:
`model.Item1 = Convert.ToDouble(ResultList[0].item1;`.

Comment: Cheers, that solved it for me. there was no intellisense prompt for the ".item1", would have taken me an age to work out what i was messing up.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast values to double.

Instead this:

```
model.item1 = Resultlist[0];
```

Do this:

```
model.item1 = (double) Resultlist[0];
```

Comment: or better yet, `double.TryParse(Resultlist[0], out double result);`